# How to deal with vimeo iframe and position fixed elements?

Tags: iframe, video, position, fixed

My site: dwapotwory.com uses embed vimeo videos. In Safari (Mac) and sometimes on Chrome (both Win/Mac) when the iframe is loaded every single element that has position: fixed (header and left/right button divs) crashes.

Without iframe in Safari everything is fine: http://dwapotwory.com/1.html

With iframe in Safari...: http://dwapotwory.com/2.html

I have the iframe wrapped in div and set to scale when scalling the browser window but it's not causing the problem (I've tried a few responsive embed vimeo solution and it didn't make any difference).

Comment: I have something similar going on, only on Safari (Desktop) with the video tag. Basically all the elements *before* the video tag go absolute where as the ones *after* get correctly positioned (fixed). In my case the parent is fixed, and the child elements absolute.

Answer (score 0):

So I run into this question because I have a similar problem with videos (just `video` tags, not actual `iframes` etc.) and fixed-positioned containers.

The Safari issues seems to be quite random, in my case I fixed it by adding -webkit-transforms to the fixed container, but in yours it can apparently be solved simply by setting a z-index to the absolute container of the frames, i tried by manipulating your DOM directly in the inspector and it seems to work.